# apt-get update error after update to 22.04

Tags: 22.04

Update today from 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 and at the end to 22.04.
All was fine until the last update.

Now I have error with apt-get update and I can not install anything.

```
marcus@nts-server:/tmp$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fel:2 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”security.ubuntu.com”
Fel:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
Fel:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
Fel:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”security.ubuntu.com”
W: Vissa indexfiler kunde inte hämtas. De har ignorerats eller så har de gamla använts istället.
```

Any solution for this?

Output from cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
marcus@nts-server:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib # inaktiverad vid uppgradering till bionic
# deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib # inaktiverad vid uppgradering till bionic
```

Comment: Try updating again, maybe it is just a temporary problem as the error said(`Temporärt fel vid uppslagning av ”se.archive.ubuntu.com”`)

Comment: Have try that a couple times with hours between but no luck :(.

Comment: Is your network working at all? Can you download with `curl` or `wget`, and can you `ping linux.com`?

Comment: Now you on to something.
It looks that the DNS lookup not working.
I kan ping 8.8.8.8 but not linux.com there I have a DNS Lookup temporally error

Comment: Then that's the problem. Please search the site for existing DNS questions - and if it doesn't help, ask a new question, focusing on the DNS part.

Comment: Thanks alot.
That was a DNS problem and now it works :)